# How to handle Union or Interface in graphQL mutations?

Tags: graphql

I got the following schema :

```
type Vehicle {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  color: String!
}

input AddVehicle {
  name: String!
  color: String!
}

input UpdateVehicle {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

Now I would like to add some properties to my vehicles, depending of the Vehicle model, like

```
type CarProperties {
  wheelSize: Int!
  doors: Int!
}

type BoatProperties {
  length: Int!
}

union VehicleProperties = CarProperties | BoatProperties

type Vehicle {
  [ ... ]
  properties: vehicleProperties!
}
```

So it's quite straightforward to write the queries, but I'm struggling when it comes to make mutations...

AFAIK graphQL inputs does not implement unions or interface (There is a related thread here https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/488)

So the workaround I see here is to duplicate my inputs, like :

```
input addBoatVehicle {
  name: String!
  color: String!
  properties: BoatProperties!
}
```

and so on with `updateBoatVehicle`, `addCarVehicle`, `updateCarVehicle`.
But if I get a lot of vehicle models, or maybe a third or a fourth mutation, I'm afraid it becomes cumbersome quickly.

Is there any recommended way to manage this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Creating separate mutations is the proper solution. You can alleviate some of the pain by making your mutations incredibly lightweight and refactor out processing of those items to a separate function.

```
function addVehicle(input) {
   // disambiguate the input type
}

function updateVehicle(input) {
  // dismabiguate the input type, preferably in its own refactor function so 
  // it can be used above too!
}

const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    addBoat: (parent, boatInput) => { return addVehicle(boatInput) },
    addCar: (parent, carInput) => { return addVehicle(carInput) },
    updateBoat: (parent, boatInput) => { return updateVehicle(boatInput) },
    updateCar: (parent, carInput) => { return updateVehicle(carInput) },
  }
}
```